# SignInWithAppleButton filling all available space

Tags: swiftui, apple-sign-in

I'm trying to integrate Apple sign in, but I have a problem with the `SignInWithAppleButton`. For example

```swift
struct DebugSignInButtonLayout_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("top with some very long text to check that wrapping is ok")
            Spacer()
            SignInWithAppleButton { _ in }
            onCompletion: { _ in }
                .frame(minHeight: 44.0)
            Spacer()
            Text("bottom with some very long text to check that wrapping is ok")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image: Button too large]

As you can see the button has decided to take up all the available space rather than appearing in the middle of the view. I can fix it by adding `.layoutPriority(1)` to everything else like this:

```swift
struct DebugSignInButtonLayout_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("top with some very long text to check that wrapping is ok").layoutPriority(1)
            Spacer().layoutPriority(1)
            SignInWithAppleButton { _ in }
            onCompletion: { _ in }
                .frame(minHeight: 44.0)
            Spacer().layoutPriority(1)
            Text("bottom with some very long text to check that wrapping is ok").layoutPriority(1)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image: Correct size]

I think that's a horrible fix because I have to apply it to everything or the text will clip instead of wrap.

How can I fix this with a better solution?

Comment: Use height instead of minHeight

Comment: I guess the Apple sign in button seems to consume all the space given to it (like a color / shape would). Hardcoding the height might not be a good idea especially with dynamic text size. If you find yourself often having to apply layoutPriority you can use the Group { }.layoutPriority(1).

Answer (score 0):

You can consider revising two things:

- Replacing .frame(minHeight: 44.0) with .frame(height: 44.0)
- Removing all instances of .layoutPriority(1)